# AuthenticateResult is returing false after successful SAML response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using SAML2 core middleware with ASP.Net for authentication.  I am able to get a successful SAML response with statuscode of 200 that I could see in the browser but my code to authenticateResult is returning false. Once the authentication is success, I am trying to get the claims and pass the user information to the application. Could someone please help?

Here is my code to **AccountController.cs :**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback(string returnUrl)
            {
                var authenticateResult1 = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

                if (authenticateResult1.Succeeded)
                {
                    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)authenticateResult1.Principal.Identity;

                    if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "ClaimTypes.Email"))
                    {
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(" ClaimTypes.Email", "Test Test"));

                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(authenticateResult1.Principal, authenticateResult1.Properties);
                    }
                }
```

Here is what I have in **startup.cs :**

````
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {

                 services.AddControllersWithViews();

                services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
                })
       .AddSamlCore(options =>
       {
           options.SignOutPath = "/signedout";
           options.ServiceProvider.EntityId = "XXXXXXXX";
           options.MetadataAddress = "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php";
           options.ForceAuthn = true;


           options.WantAssertionsSigned = true;
           options.RequireMessageSigned = false;
           options.UseTokenLifetime = false;

           // Service Provider Properties (optional) - These set the appropriate tags in the metadata.xml file
           options.ServiceProvider.ServiceName = "XXXXX";
           options.ServiceProvider.Language = "en-US";
           options.ServiceProvider.OrganizationDisplayName = "XXXXXXX";
           options.ServiceProvider.OrganizationName = "xxxxxxxxx";
           options.ServiceProvider.OrganizationURL = "https://xxxxxxx.com";
           options.ServiceProvider.ContactPerson = new ContactType()
           {
               Company = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
               GivenName = "Guy Fawks",
               EmailAddress = new[] { "someemailhere@xxxxxxxx.com" },
             //  contactType = ContactTypeType.technical,
               TelephoneNumber = new[] { "+1 234 5678" }
           };
           //Events - Modify events below if you want to log errors, add custom claims, etc.
           options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
           {
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           };
           options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
           { 
               var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
               var claims = context.Principal.Claims;
               if (claims.Any(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
               {
                   var userId = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
                   var name = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                   identity.TryRemoveClaim(name);
                   identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userId));
               }

               return Task.FromResult(0);
           };
       })

            .AddCookie();
                services.AddMvc();
            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //To show detail of error and see the problem
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseAuthentication(); // AT modified on 4/17
                app.UseAuthorization();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
        }
    }
    ```
````